# Не работает логическое условие

Tags: php

Прописал условие:

```
if(  $val !== '0' || $kay !== 'color' ){}
```

По отдельности каждое условие срабатывает, но вместе - нет. Брать в скобки каждое условие тоже пробовал.

Более полный пример:

```
$ar = array( 'color' => 'цвет', 'one' => 1, 's' => 0 );

foreach($ar as $kay => $val){

if( $kay !== 'color' ||  $val !== 0 ){

  print $val . '<br>';  
}}
```

Условие не срабатывает.

Comment: Нужно именно ИЛИ, `OR` `||`  , то есть выполнить условие, если значение не равно 0, а ключ не равен обозначенному слову, одновременно эти два условия не совпадают, то есть нет ключа `color` со значением `0` .

Comment: Тогда все работает именно так как вы и хотели, если объясняете правильно. Пример https://ideone.com/qeMFJM  Разумеется последнее условие YES потому что числовой ноль и символьный это разные вещи для !==

Comment: Приведите пример, который действительно не срабатывает. Продемонстрируйте это на ideone.com. Ваш текущий код отлично печатает все 3 значения https://ideone.com/CuoL3Q  А если он у вас в точности такой и не работает, значит у вас проблема где нибудь совершенно в другом месте, например он не вызывается

Comment: Ошибка как раз в том, что он печатает три значения, а должен только одно, то, в котором ключ не равен `color` и значение ` !== 0`, под это условие подпадает только среднее значение. Или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Ваша фраза "_а должен только одно, то, в котором ключ не равен color И значение !== 0_". Обратите внимание на "И" которое вы написали. Почему же вы тогда в if пишите "ИЛИ" ? https://ideone.com/CuoL3Q

Comment: И еще вы всех запутали свои комментарием "_то есть нет ключа color со значением 0_". В вашем текущем примере как раз нет ключа color со значением 0, у ключа color значение "цвет"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Одновременно не совпадают" это И, а не ИЛИ

```
if ($val !== '0' && $kay !== 'color'){}
```

Comment: Это условие никогда не сработает. (ссылка на предыдущий комментарий)

Comment: Тогда разберитесь с тем, что вам нужно, и объясните нормально. Исходя из текущего описания это именно то, что вам требуется.